# TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

Here is my code:

```
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
gen = img_gen.flow_from_directory('/train/',(224, 224),'rgb', batch_size = 2)
training_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda : gen, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes = ([2,224,224,3],[2,2]))

def read_images(features):
    return features['image']

training_set = training_set.map(lambda x: read_images(x), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

The error was:

```
    TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

So how can I solve the problem in funtion read_images.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of [flow_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) -

> Returns
> A DirectoryIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a
> numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size,
> *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.

You can see that it returns a tuple with 2 elements, so your map function needs to handle that.

```
def read_images(features):
    # some processing
    output = features
    return output

training_set = training_set.map(lambda image, label: read_images(image), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

The [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) itself have a lot of processing options available.
You can also check out other tutorials in tensorflow pages - [load images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images)

Looking at the dataset content would also help debug issues

```
for line in training_set.take(1):
    print(len(line))
    print(line)
```